# Is there a way to render two partial views in C# MVC such that they appear side by side in a single view?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am somewhat new to C# MVC and have been utilizing partial views in my solution. When I render two or more partial views in a single view, I see that they get rendered from top to bottom (when they are rendered, they appear on the page one on top of the next), which is what I would expect.

Is there a way to specify that partial views get rendered instead in a side to side or grid fashion? I ask because there is a lot of white space and it would be ideal to place the content from some of the partial views in this white space.

Comment: To be fair I don't think this is anything to do with asp.net. C# or partial views and is a HTML and CSS issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Example 1

You *could* wrap your partial views in some `div` elements and set them to `display: inline-block`, this will make them appear side by side.

CSS Styling:

```
div.sidebyside { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
```

View:

```
<div class="sidebyside">@Render.Partial(...)</div>
<div class="sidebyside">@Render.Partial(...)</div>
```

### Example 2

You *could* arrange the `div`s into a table layout:

CSS Styling:

```
div.table { display: table; }
div.row { display: table-row; }
div.cell { display: table-cell; }
```

View:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">@Render.Partial(...)</div>
        <div class="cell">@Render.Partial(...)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was looking for; thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. This has to do with your styling (CSS). 
You might want to check this out to get the basic idea:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/db2972/partial-view-sample-in-mvc-day-35/

Comment: Please don't use tables for page layout :o(

Comment: Thought he just might not be familiar with divs, and tables are easy to get a grip on before going on to divs. But yes of course you are right, the most efficient way is to use divs for styling but he can might as well use HTML5 elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't comes from the "PartialView" component.
The classic behavior for html element is to be displayed vertically : https://jsfiddle.net/xff9qvn6/

You have several solutions to align them horizontally :

- Using `<table>` tag : https://jsfiddle.net/xff9qvn6/5/
- Using `display:inline-block` css style : https://jsfiddle.net/xff9qvn6/4/
- Using `float:left` css style : https://jsfiddle.net/xff9qvn6/3/

Answer (score 0):

I just used display:flex

Boom side by side partial views.